# How can a country imprison people without violating UDHR article 3?

Tags: human-rights

I am surprised I cannot find any information on this topic on SE Law, as it seems to be an obvious question; when reading the Universal Declaration of Human Rights, I was wondering:

**The Universal Declaration of Human Rights article 3 states that everyone has the right to liberty. How is it that countries can imprison criminals without violating this article?**

Should I interpret this as *a Utopian situation which has not been achieved by far*, or *a 'right to try to escape from prison'*, or something totally different?

Comment: See also Article 8: "Everyone has the right to an effective remedy by the competent national tribunals for acts violating the fundamental rights granted him by the constitution or by law." If imprisonment is deemed the effective remedy for a particular crime (e.g. murder, manslaughter, assualt, etc.), then as long as you convict and imprison him in accordance with Articles  5, 9, 10 and 11, then it seems to me that you are still adhering to the UDHR with respect to the criminal's human rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Universal Declaration of Human Rights is first of all, not self-executing and doesn't have legal effect of its own.

Secondly, it is generally recognized that all rights are subject to reasonable regulation and restriction.

Comment: And do you mean total liberty for everyone is regarded as 'the ultimate goal'? Because otherwise, I do not see the (technical) reason to add it to the UDHR.

Comment: @aaphond You are unreasonably assuming that a "right to liberty" implies a right to "total liberty" or even a goal of "total liberty". Liberty within reason and subject to reasonable regulation is the goal, not "total liberty".

Answer (score 1):

The right to liberty includes a right not to be robbed, murdered or raped. Article 30 of the Declaration states

> Nothing in this Declaration may be interpreted as implying for any
>   State, group or person any right to engage in any activity or to
>   perform any act aimed at the destruction of any of the rights and
>   freedoms set forth herein.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate the second part a bit? Because I don't understand what this implies.

Comment: The right to liberty also includes the right to do the business that you want to and keep the profits if that business. And yet...